# Json passing multiple objects

Tags: c#, json

I have an object called Weapons which contains damage, reload speed and magazine (ints). I need to pass at least two objects each time. For a single object, I used:

```
string single = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object);
```

And it's working.

For multiple objects, I tried to use foreach with concat:

```
string ws = "";

foreach (var weapon in weapons(from database))
{
    Weapon weaponJson = new Weapon()
    {
        Damage = weapon.Damage,
        ReloadSpeed = weapon.ReloadSpeed,
        MagazineSize = weapon.Magazine
    };

    ws = String.Concat(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(weaponsJson));
}
```

But when I deserialize, only the first object is returned. I have read many things about that and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Any reason why you aren't just serializing these as a list?

Comment: Or try :

`ws += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(weaponsJson);`

Comment: Your `String.Concat` line isn't concatenating with anything, it's just overwriting `ws` every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick the objects into a list and then serialise the list.

```
List<Weapon> weapons = new List<Weapon>();
foreach(var weapon in database.weapons)
{
    weapons.add(new Weapon 
                    { 
                        // initialise from db fields 
                    });
}  
ws = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(weapons);
```

Comment: That is exacly what i needed. Here is how to deserialize: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Object>>